# "Most days" or "On most days"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, determiners

Which sentences are correct?

1. > It was raining most days.
2. > It was raining on most days.
3. > It was raining most mornings.
4. > It was raining in most mornings.

I've seen **most** as a determiner used both with and without prepositions. And I couldn't find a rule on what usage is correct.

Comment: 4 sounds very incorrect, and 2 sounds a little less incorrect, but is still wrong. 1 and 3 are the best, but using "It rained most days" and "it rained most mornings" sounds better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In* with time expressions is used when you are saying after a specific interval of time, something will happen (i.e. *In two hours, I'm leaving*.)

If you want to say something is happening at a certain time of day (or certain day of the week, certain day of the month, etc.) use *on* (except for clock time, use *at*).

So 4 is wrong.

Now given:

> It was raining most days.
>
> It was raining most mornings.

An adverb can be preceded with *most*, and many times adverbs/adverbial phrases can be flexible where they appear in the sentence, with some positions usually perferred over others:

> I flawlessly attacked the enemy.
>
> I attacked the enemy most flawlessly.

So I think here "most days" or "most mornings" works as adverbial phrase that modifies *was raining* - especially since adverbial phrases can be moved and something like *Most days it was raining* still means the same thing.

So you can omit the preposition or keep it, the meaning is pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0):

1 and 3 may be more suitable as an answer than 2 or 4